# Weird setTimeout issue

Tags: javascript, events, settimeout

I have this problem. I defined a function to remove a link (just for the sake of example), so I want that after a mouseleave event on the link, it will disappear after 5 seconds (or whatever). Furthermore, if I mouseenter over the same link (which ostensibly has setTimeout running), that setTimeout is cancelled. For example, the following code works but as I'm not defining my setTimeout, I can't cancel it.

```
function func() { $('a').remove(); }
    //var interval = setTimeout( func , 5000);

    $('body').on('mouseleave', 'a', function() {
        setTimeout( func , 5000);
    });

    $('body').on('mouseenter', 'a', function(){
    //    clearTimeout(interval)
    });
```

Instead, uncommenting the second line, makes the link disappear immediately, even although I'm using the function `func` without parenthesis, so I would have thought that wouldn't be a problem ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cRwCC/4/)):

```
function func() { $('a').remove(); }
    var interval = setTimeout( func , 5000);

    $('body').on('mouseleave', 'a', function() {
        interval
    });

    $('body').on('mouseenter', 'a', function(){
    //    clearTimeout(interval)
    });
```

What can I do to achieve the intended functionality?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combinerate (yes, that's a technical term) your two attempts. Declare `interval` outside of `func` *and* the mouse handlers, so that it can be referenced by both handlers.

```
function func() {
    $('a').remove();
}

var interval;

$('body').on('mouseleave', 'a', function() {
    interval = setTimeout(func, 5000);
});

$('body').on('mouseenter', 'a', function() {
    clearTimeout(interval);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/2XN9a/

Comment: Yup. You were so close! You should try poking around in your debugger to see what's happening next time.

Comment: I was using console.log quite a bit, but I didn't occur to me to define 'interval' outside AND using interval = setTimeout inside the mouseleave function.

Comment: `console.log` is only one of the many tools in the debugging arsenal. I meant: setting breakpoints, stepping through code – _that_ sort of debugging.

Comment: Usually I do that... I will do it more frequently :-)